# Google Chrome does now show grey circle

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a little problem. When i enable dev tools and mobile screen emulation with touch emulation, a grey circle cursor should be for my cursor, but i, for some reason do not see it, while cursor is on screen (no cursor totally). However, it would be visible on screenshot (why?).

---

#### Environment :

```
Chrome version : 48.0.2564.109
Windows version : 8.1 x64
```

Comment: Try resetting Chrome DevTools data: Settings -> Restore defaults and reload. (Warning! This will reset all DevTools data, including deletion of snippets!). Overall, this looks like a bug.

Comment: Resetting settings didn't helped. This "bug" was, when i installed Chrome to my computer. I tried to reinstall it, and reset user in chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i solved this problem! This is also adresses to a problem with drop shadow from windows and cursor. I have an intel core i5 6xxx, which has some problems with it. I am sorry, if my translation is not good enough.

Solution: Open your intel graphics settings, then, go to advanced and enable full sample range. Then open color settings and go advanced and disable YCbCr.